# Consider defining a bean of type 'javax.servlet.ServletContext'

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am doing a Spring Boot Website and I'm stuck with the error: **Parameter 6 of constructor in springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper required a bean of type 'javax.servlet.ServletContext' that could not be found.**

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.leonard</groupId>
    <artifactId>joblisting</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>joblisting</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        this one to compile classpath-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My JoblistingApplication.java:

```
package com.leonard.joblisting;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
public class JoblistingApplication {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(RestController.class)).paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build().apiInfo(apiInfo()).useDefaultResponseMessages(false);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        final ApiInfoBuilder builder = new ApiInfoBuilder();
        return builder.build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JoblistingApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Could you show me is there any error with the version of depencies? What I should do?

Comment: have you defined such a bean?

Comment: I'm new to this one and the error tell me to define a bean, I'm not sure what I should do cause the tutorial that I follow could run this code.